# if statement to check $HOSTNAME in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, testing

So I want to set some paths differently depending on the host, but unfortunately it's not working. Here is my script:

```
if [$HOSTNAME == "foo"]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failure"
fi
```

This is what happens:

```
-bash: [foo: command not found
failure
```

I know for certain that $HOSTNAME is foo, so I'm not sure what the problem is. I am pretty new to bash though. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the shell is whitespace sensitive. `[x` is different from `[ x`.

Comment: Hint: The test operator for string equality is `=`, not `==`, even though the latter is accepted by buggy shells in a misguided attempt to ease programmers with less error messages.

Comment: @Jens can you elaborate on the attempt being misguided, it seems that `==` is a fairly standard equality operator syntax? I'm a software engineer now really using shell a lot these days and I'm just curious.

Comment: @nulltron The Standard is the Opengroup's UNIX specification and in that grammar only `=` is the comparison operator for `test`. Many years ago some shells started to make `==` synonymous. This made scripts using `==` suddenly non-portable and ill-behaved on conformant shells (of which there were many, and some still are around).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The POSIX and portable way to compare strings in the shell is

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = foo ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "on the right host"
else
    printf '%s\n' "uh-oh, not on foo"
fi
```

A case statement may be more flexible, though:

```
case $HOSTNAME in
  (foo) echo "Woohoo, we're on foo!";;
  (bar) echo "Oops, bar? Are you kidding?";;
  (*)   echo "How did I get in the middle of nowhere?";;
esac
```

Comment: One, and only one. That's POSIX. Anything else is a bogus shell, accepting more than it should, promoting the `==` noncompliant script disease.

Comment: What is the diff between `hostname` and `HOSTNAME`? For comparison I need `HOSTNAME`. On `wsl`, hostname returns `wsl` and `HOSTNAME` the windows host.

Comment: @Jens nvm found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space after the opening bracket. It's also good "not to parse" the variable content using double quotes:

```
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "foo" ]; then 
    ...
```

Comment: Double `==` is a bug. The equality operator is `=`. Some shells only accept it because of widespread ignorance :-)

Comment: You're right that it's not 100% POSIX correct, but I always tend to use == if it works.

Comment: You should rethink the "if it works" attitude. It won't work on many a popular shell, while = will work everwhere on any Unix since the epoch. One day you will find yourself on such a system. Ever heard of Solaris? And = is even less to type than ==.

Comment: There are many utilities that are kind of platform specific. I do care if there's a possibility that my script won't work. When I write a simple script for myself, who cares.

Comment: Attention to detail is the hallmark of professional programming. Why would anyone be less caring for their own scripting? I am caring, and I wish more people were, because it gets you in a habit of writing bullet-proof code from the start.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(hostname) == "home" ]] || [[ $(hostname) == "home2" ]]; then
    echo "True"
fi
```